# Adding some marks on a dashboard's map

Tags: javascript, html, maps, coordinates, dashboard

First of all, sorry for my english.
Then, my question:
I try to modify these Chrome extension:
https://github.com/mak08/VRDashboard

In order to add some "marks" or points (for which I have coordinates), in the Map area.
I tried to modify the api key but that's not relevant...

How can I do, please?
I checked into dashboard.html, and found some informations about Google's API but that's all.
Maybe should I add the coordinates in the "dashboard.js" file but i'm not sure...

Thanks for your help!

C